# Don't show thumbnails if Galleria has only one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I'm using Galleria (http://galleria.io/) and generating images to the gallery dynamically, once in a while there's a situation where a gallery includes just one image, at that point I'd like the gallery to appear without the thumbnail container, how could I do this?

Any help greatly appreciated!

My current script for initializing is:

```
Galleria.loadTheme('assets/js/galleria.classic.min.js');

// Initialize Galleria
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
  show: selectedIndex,
  showInfo: false,
  swipe: true,
  imageCrop: false,
  responsive:true,
  showCounter:true,
  thumbnails:true,
  lightbox: true,
  trueFullscreen:true,
  extend: function() {
    this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function() {
      $('#description').html(this.$('info-title').html());
      $('.galleria-lightbox-title').html(this.$('info-title').html());
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try thumbnails: $("#galleria img").size()>1

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#galleria img:only-child').hide();
```

You need to select the child element of the parent when it is only singular - one thumbnail - the jQuery selector `only-child` allows this - then chain the statement to `hide()` to hide it.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!